# Batch adjust times on files

Tags: batch-file

I just filmed a wedding, using two different cameras, and realized after the wedding that I corrected only one camera for daylight savings time. My editing software automatically (albeit roughly) arranges the video clips on the timeline based on the time stamps in the file's properties. It would save an incredible amount of time if I could add one hour (plus/minus a couple minutes or seconds, the time synchronization was apparently not perfect) to all of the files in a given folder.

I've found some freeware online that allows me to change all of the files simultaneously, so it resets every file to have the same creation time, rather than just add some preset time to each file. I am not very apt to use or run code, so please keep that in mind when providing ideas! Any and all are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know you can only update the date `modified` property, to current date, of a file with batch using - `copy /b full-path+,, full-path` ...You will probably need to look at [third party software](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+date+property+files) to achieve what you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a powershell one-liner to do what you need I think.

Open a `cmd` console and `cd` into the directory containing the clips you want to modify.  Then to add an hour to every file's timestamp you'd just

```js
powershell "gci | %{ $_.LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime.addHours(1) }"
```

You can do the same thing with `.addMinutes` as well if you wish.  If you want to manipulate the last modified time of an individual file, instead of using `Get-ChildItem | foreach` (or `gci | %` as I have it shortened), do

```js
powershell "$f = gi filename.ext; $f.LastWriteTime = $f.LastWriteTime.addHours(1)"
```

If you mess up and need to subtract hours, do `.addHours(-1)`.

If you have questions, please bear in mind that this is a programming website.  If you are uncomfortable navigating the windows file system through a `cmd` window or need other basic assistance, then [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) would probably be a more appropriate place to ask.